# How can I delete keys by iterating over an array of hashes and by considering 2 hashes at a time?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, duplicates, iteration

I have an array of hashes. I want to iterate over it and would like to compare 2 hashes at a time and remove a key, value pair (from one hash) from the first hash when there is the same key in both hashes.

For example:

```
log = [{"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"},{"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE", "robin"=>"THERE"}]
```

In the above array, there is one key that is common in both the hashes which is `"robin"`. I would like to remove `"robin"=>"THERE"` from the second hash, while the first hash remains unchanged.

Also, the keys could be anything. they are not fixed key names

I have tried `(h1.keys & h2.keys).each {|k| puts ( h1[k] == h2[k] ? h1[k] : k ) }`, but I am trying to see if I can do it programmatically even if there are more than two hashes in the array.

Answer (score 1):

### Iterate Through Consecutive Pairs and Delete Matching Keys from Second Element

If you want to compare two arrays at a time from an array of hashes, you can compare each element of the array to the previous one using [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). Then, for each pair of consecutive hashes, simply delete the matching keys from the *second* hash using [Hash#delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if).

```
log = [
  {"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"},
  {"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE", "robin"=>"THERE"},
]

log.each_cons(2) do |hash1, hash2|
  hash2.delete_if { |k,v| hash1.has_key? k }
end

log
#=> [{"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"}, {"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE"}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Todd for the response. But This one is not comparing the 1st and the last hash in the array. It's going sequentially. 
Let's say we have 4 hashes in an array, then it needs to compare (1,2), (2,3), (3,4) and (1,4) as well right.

Comment: @Robin You're partially right. If you want to compare all hashes to all other hashes, you could try iterating over an Array#permutation, but I think you have some underlying assumptions that you haven't explained. If you want to remove "duplicate" keys, deciding *which* values to keep in a non-consecutive comparison is undefined by your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

```
log = [
  {"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"},
  {"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE", "robin"=>"THERE", "lois"=>"HUH" },
  {"trixie"=>"HO", "joey"=>"BYE", "robin"=>"THERE","bubba"=>"WHERE"},
  {"billie-bob"=>"YO", "bubba"=>"SHARE", "robin"=>"THERE"}
]
```

As I understand, for each pair of consecutive elements in `log` (hashes), each key of the first hash that is also a key of the second hash is to be removed from the first hash. (At the end I consider also removing keys in the last hash that are present in the first hash, as mentioned by the OP in a comment.)

There are many ways to do this. Here is one.

```
new_keys = (log.map(&:keys) << []).each_cons(2).map { |a1,a2| a1-a2 }
  #=> [["sasha"], ["jack", "lois"], ["trixie", "joey"], 
  #    ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"]]
arr = log.map!.with_index { |h,i| h.slice(*new_keys[i]) }
  #=> [{"sasha"=>"HELLO"}, {"jack"=>"HI", "lois"=>"HUH"},
  #    {"trixie"=>"HO", "joey"=>"BYE"},
  #    {"billie-bob"=>"YO", "bubba"=>"SHARE", "robin"=>"THERE"}]
```

We can confirm the original hashes were modified:

```
arr == log
  #=> true
```

If it were desired to return a new array of hashes and not mutate `log`, substitute [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) for [Array#map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21).

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

The first operation, computing the new keys for each hash, involves the following steps.

```
  a = log.map(&:keys)
    #=> [["sasha", "robin"], ["jack", "joey", "robin", "lois"],
    #    ["trixie", "joey", "robin", "bubba"],
    #    ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"]] 
  b = a << []
    #=> [["sasha", "robin"], ["jack", "joey", "robin", "lois"],
    #    ["trixie", "joey", "robin", "bubba"],
    #    ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"], []] 
  enum = b.each_cons(2)
    #=> #<Enumerator: [["sasha", "robin"],...
    #     ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"], []]:each_cons(2)>
```

We can see the elements that the enumerator `enum` will generate and pass to `map` by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[["sasha", "robin"], ["jack", "joey", "robin", "lois"]],
  #    [["jack", "joey", "robin", "lois"],
  #     ["trixie", "joey", "robin", "bubba"]],
  #    [["trixie", "joey", "robin", "bubba"],
  #     ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"]],
  #    [["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"], []]]
```

It is seen that each element generated is an array of two arrays holding the keys of two successive hashes in `log`. Continuing,

```
new_keys = enum.map { |a1,a2| a1-a2 }
  #=> [["sasha"], ["jack", "lois"], ["trixie", "joey"],
  #    ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"]]
```

It should now be evident why we needed the last array generated by `enum` to contain the keys of the last hash of `log` and an empty array. That way the last hash in `log` is not modified.

It is not necessary to compute the new keys for each element of `log` as a first step, but doing so has the advantage that it avoids the need to extract the keys for each pair of contiguous hashes, which would require `2*(log.size) - 1` operations.

The second operation, using `new_keys` to modify the existing hashes, involves the following steps.

```
enum0 = log.map!
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"sasha"=>"HELLO"},...
  #     "bubba"=>"SHARE", "robin"=>"THERE"}]:map!> 
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [{"sasha"=>"HELLO"},...
  #     "bubba"=>"SHARE", "robin"=>"THERE"}]:map!>:with_index>
```

The first element is generated by `enum1` and passed to the block (a two-element array), which is divided into it's two elements, which in turn are assigned to the two block variables. The process of doing this is called  [abbreviated assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment).

```
h,i = enum1.next
  #=> [{"sasha"=>"HELLO"}, 0] 
h #=> {"sasha"=>"HELLO"} 
i #=> 0
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
a = new_keys[i]
  #=> ["sasha"] 
h.slice(*a)
  #=> {"sasha"=>"HELLO"}
```

The first element of `log` is therefore replaced by `{"sasha"=>"HELLO"}`. Next,

```
h,i = enum1.next
  #=> [{"trixie"=>"HO", "joey"=>"BYE"}, 2] 
h #=> {"trixie"=>"HO", "joey"=>"BYE"} 
i #=> 2 
a = new_keys[i]
  #=> ["trixie", "joey"] 
h.slice(*a)
  #=> {"trixie"=>"HO", "joey"=>"BYE"}
```

The remaining steps are similar.

If it were desired to also remove keys from that last hash in `log` that were also present in the first hash in `log`, the first step would be changed as follows.

```
new_keys = (log.map(&:keys) << log.first.keys).
             each_cons(2).map { |a1,a2| a1-a2 }
  #=> [["sasha"], ["jack", "lois"], ["trixie", "joey"],
  #    ["billie-bob", "bubba"]]
```

as

```
log.map(&:keys) << log.first.keys
  #=> [["sasha", "robin"], ["jack", "joey", "robin", "lois"],
  #    ["trixie", "joey", "robin", "bubba"],
  #    ["billie-bob", "bubba", "robin"], ["sasha", "robin"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for pairs of hashes to be compared even if they aren't consecutive. `Array#combination` helps with this. You tell it how many elements you want to "consider" at a time (this number of elements are yielded to the block).

```rb
log = [
  {"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"},
  {"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE", "robin"=>"THERE"},
  {"sasha"=>"GONE", "jane"=>"KEEP"},
  {"jack"=>"RM", "mary"=>"STAY"}
]

# yield all combinations of the elements, taken 2 at a time
log.combination(2) { |h1, h2|
  (h1.keys & h2.keys).each { |k|
    # delete from 2nd hash, but you can easily delete from the first if desired
    h2.delete(k)
  }
}

log
=> [{"sasha"=>"HELLO", "robin"=>"HI"}, {"jack"=>"HI", "joey"=>"BYE"}, {"jane"=>"KEEP"}, {"mary"=>"STAY"}]
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination for more info on the concept of combinations.